# How to replace from x import * to import x in python code?

Tags: python, parsing, pyqt, abstract-syntax-tree, sublime-text-plugin

I have a bunch of long pyqt scripts, in which the original author wrote code like this

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
...
```

Is there a smart or quick way to change the code to

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
...
```

and also prefix every pyqt class with module name? eg
change `QDialog` to `QtGui.QDialog`, with sublime editor or pycharm ? or any other editor?

I read about one can add custom fixers to 2to3 script, and repurpose that tool for this, but that doesn't seem a simple task. Or build ast tree and do the replace by yourself ( sounds more complex and maybe it is reinventing the wheel ). Or should I just write regex replace script and just parse all the .py files ? ( sounds unsafe )

edit: I read the original question, it seems my question is a subset of it, finally I used a hacky solution, since I knew the code I want to fix is pyqt.

```
bad_file = '/path/to/bad_file'
import re

from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

QtCore_mappings = [x for x in dir(QtCore) if '_' not in x]
QtGui_mappings = [x for x in dir(QtGui) if '_' not in x]

mappings = {'QtCore':QtCore_mappings,'QtGui':QtGui_mappings }

cache={}


def find_class_long_name(c):
    for k,v in mappings.iteritems():
        if c in v:
            return '%s.%s' % (k,c)
    else:
        return None

with open(bad_file) as f:
    code = f.read()

    all_classes =  re.findall(r'\bQ[A-Z]\w*\b', code)
    all_classes=set(all_classes)

    for c in all_classes:
        new_c = find_class_long_name(c)
        if new_c:
            print '%s ---> %s' % (c, new_c)
            code=re.sub(r'\b%s\b' %c,new_c,code)
        else:
            print 'skipped:',c

        # write code to new file
```

update 2：
Ｉ think I can just replace the module import lines without changing the code

```
def find_module(c):
    for k,v in mappings.iteritems():
        if c in v:
            return k
    else:
        return None

with open(bad_file) as f:
    code = f.read()
    # print code

    all_classes =  re.findall(r'\bQ[A-Z]\w*\b', code)
    all_classes=set(all_classes)

    for c in all_classes:
        c_module = find_module(c)
        if c_module:
            cache[c_module].append(c)
        else:
            print 'skipped:',c

    cmd = ''
    for k,v in cache.iteritems():
        if cache[k]:
            cmd+='from %s import (%s)' % (k, ', '.join(sorted(cache[k])))
            cmd+='\n'

    print 'new import:\n'
    print cmd
```

Comment: If I may ask. How many `from x import *` are we talking about?

Comment: In several hundreds of files, the problem is in the code, every usage of PyQt classes does not have `QtGui.` or `QtCore.` as a prefix

Comment: That is a problem. Maybe you can think about running `pylint` once you replace everything to get a list of import errors and then add it to `from x import y, z`?